# How can I dynamically divide columns based on n number of columns into different tables in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a query that returns data as below:

```
ID      Date            Date_flag
1       10-07/10/2016   1
1       1-06/10/2016    2
1       11-07/11/2016   3
1       12-07/13/2016   4
1       13-07/14/2016   5
2       10-07/10/2016   1
2       11-07/11/2016   2
2       12-07/13/2016   3
2       13-07/14/2016   4
2       14-07/15/2016   5
```

I am creating a matrix in SSRS where Column group is based on `Date` and Row group is based on `ID` and data is to count # of rows. So here is my what my data looks like in a SSRS matrix:

```
H_Level 10-07/10/2016   1-06/10/2016    11-07/11/2016   12-07/13/2016   13-07/14/2016   14-07/15/2016
1       1               0               1               1               1               0
2       1               1               1               1               1               1
```

Now the problem I am having is that I can only have three columns in one matrix at a time. So my matrix should split to two matrix (in this scenario). I need to make it dynamic because in future I can have more dates which means more columns. How do I make a dynamic matrix and have it break on every 3 columns? When the matrix break I want the header to display again. Is this possible in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

You can do pivot like below:

```
Select * from (
    Select Id, [Date], 1 as Val from YourDates ) a
    pivot (max([Val]) for [date] in ([10-07/10/2016],[1-06/10/2016 ],[11-07/11/2016],[12-07/13/2016],[13-07/14/2016],[14-07/15/2016]) ) p
```

For dynamic list of columns you can query as below:

```
declare @cols1 varchar(max)
declare @cols2 varchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName([Date]) from YourDates for xml path('')),1,1,'')
Select @cols2 = stuff((Select Distinct ','+'COALESCE('+QuoteName([Date])+', 0) as ' + QuoteName([Date])  from YourDates for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Select @Query = ' Select Id, ' + @cols2 + ' from (
    Select Id, [Date], 1 as Val from YourDates ) a
    pivot (max([Val]) for [date] in (' + @cols1 + ') ) p'

--Select @Query
exec sp_executesql @Query
```

Output as below

```
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Id | 10-07/10/2016 | 1-06/10/2016  | 11-07/11/2016 | 12-07/13/2016 | 13-07/14/2016 | 14-07/15/2016 |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|  1 |             1 |             1 |             1 |             1 |             1 |             0 |
|  2 |             1 |             0 |             1 |             1 |             1 |             1 |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think you didn't read my question properly. I don't have a problem with getting data in SQL, I can do that. The problem is in SSRS. I need only three columns per matrix/table and other three in 2nd matrix, or 3rd or 4th. I need to assign a limitation on columns of SSRS matrix/table, but the column numbers need to be dynamic as I don't know how many will be generated

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the hidden problem is the possible large length of the table. If that so, why don't you just switch the columns for H_Level and Id. You will loop throught the date.

This way you have just 3 columns and the length of the data will not be a problem.